# How to print "-" using printf

Tags: bash, printf

I am trying to print "-" multiple times using `printf`. I am using the below command to print the same character multiple times, which works fine for all except "-".

```
printf "`printf '=%.0s' {1..30}` \n"
```

When I try to do the same for "-", it gives error.

```
printf "`printf '-%.0s' {1..30}` \n"
bash: printf: -%: invalid option
```

It is trying to take it as user-passed option. How do I work around this?

Comment: @TomFenech To get a linebreak, I guess.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pass `--` before everything else to each `printf` invocation:

```
printf -- "`printf -- '-%.0s' {1..30}` \n"
```

Like many commands, `printf` takes options in the form of tokens starting with `-` (although `-v` and `--` are the only options I know). This interferes with your argument string, as `printf` is instead trying to parse `-%.0s` as an option. For that case however, it supports the `--` option (like many other commands), which terminates option parsing and passes through all following arguments literally.

Comment: @Sigura This works perfectly....and it resolved another of my problem as well...
When we use printf to print list of files with permissions, it fails due to '-r' in '-rwx'.

Answer (score 2):

Are you trying to print 30 hyphens? This is how I do that:

```
printf "%*s\n" 30 "" | sed 's/ /-/g'
```

The printf command prints a line with 30 spaces, then use sed to turn them all into hyphens

This can be encapsulated into a function:

```
ruler() { printf "%*s\n" "$1" "" | sed "s/ /${2//\//\\\/}/g"; }
```

And then you can do stuff like:

```
ruler $(tput cols) =
```

Comment: This can get a bit complicated, if I'm trying to do something like this -- printf "`printf '-%.0s' {1..30}` \n$<Same Statement/Variable \n`printf '-%.0s' {1..30}` \n"

Comment: I don't understand your comment. use backticks for code formatting, and use `$()` in your code instead of backticks